# AngularJS $resource class vs. instance methods

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource, angularjs-factory

I define a factory for "Dashboard":

```
myApp.factory('Dashboard', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  return $resource("/dashboards/:id", { id: "@id" },
    {
      'create':  { method: 'POST' },
      'index':   { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
      'show':    { method: 'GET', isArray: false },
      'update':  { method: 'PUT' },
      'destroy': { method: 'DELETE' }
    }
  );
}]);
```

In order to update a dashboard I need to use the **class method**:

```
$scope.dashboard = Dashboard.get({ id: 1234 });
Dashboard.update({ id: $scope.dashboard.id }, $scope.dashboard);
```

Instead is there a way I can call it as an **instance method** of a particular dashboard?

```
$scope.dashboard = Dashboard.get({id: 1234 });
$scope.dashboard.update();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).

About halfway down:

> The action methods on the class object or instance object can be invoked with the following parameters:
>
> HTTP GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], [success], [error])
>
> non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])
>
> non-GET instance actions: instance.$action([parameters], [success], [error])

And an example from their page:

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
var user = User.get({userId:123}, function() {
  user.abc = true;
  user.$save();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I read the docs before posting.  They do not specify how to define a non-GET instance action.  I tried using the non-GET instance action (as shown in the question), but this syntax does not work.

Comment: You tried (in your code) `dashboard.$save` and/or `dashboard.$update`? What does not work - it throws an error?

Comment: Ohh, I was missing the $ sign in front of update. So `$scope.dashboard.$update()` works, while I was trying `$scope.dashboard.update()`.

Comment: Is there any option like instance actions: instance.$action(postData, [success], [error]). For example /users/:id/upload